# emacs style autocompletion (alt+/) in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emacs, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

Intellisense is fine in various Visual Studio editors (C#, VB...).

However, in various other cases, your typing productivity drops dramatically because Intellisense simply does not apply (XML without XSDs, simple text files).

Emacs and eclipse have a simple, generic answer to these situations: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> **autocompletion**.

By repetitively pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> the editor will cycle through word-completion suggestions.
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> has no concept of the target buffer syntax (it can be text) and will just handle words.  The suggested words are filtered as matching the already typed characters in reverse appearance order.

**Question:**
Is there any way to emulate this shortcut in VS2012 (+Resharper 7.1) - or even previous versions for that matter?
My brain is now hardwired to use it and I feel like I've lost half of my fingers when I switch from eclipse to VS.

**Caution:**
I'm not asking for a way to import the full emacs set of shortcuts (as I'd prefer to avoid collisions and I want to stick to the standard VS shortcut culture for the rest of the IDE, mixing with resharper is hard enough).